# App crashing while calling FragmentActivity in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Trying to display viewPager in Navigation drawer first tab ,here is my main activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;   
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.globussoft.model.NavDrawerItem2;
import com.globussoft.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem2> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem2>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Today
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem2(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Hottest
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem2(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Random
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem2(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // All
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem2(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.icon_launcher, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        this.getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent firstpage= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DefaultTabs.class);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(firstpage);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new HottestFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new RandomFragment();
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment = new AllFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Here facing problem in first tab content displaying.please check `displayView()` .In case 0 i am getting **error in creating fragment** In other cases i am creating fragments by extending Fragment class but but for case 0 i.e DefaultTabs class extending FragmentActivity .so i am calling DefaultTabs class like this

```
Intent firstpage= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DefaultTabs.class);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(firstpage);
```

here is my DefaultTabs class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.globussoft.adapter.AllPagerTabsAdapter;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

public class DefaultTabs extends FragmentActivity {

    public AllPagerTabsAdapter pagerTabsAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_tabs, container,false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         pagerTabsAdapter = new AllPagerTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

         ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
         pager.setAdapter(pagerTabsAdapter);

         TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
         indicator.setViewPager(pager);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace, so we can better understand the nature of the crash.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gGXceas2

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

With

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

**NOTE:**

Apply same thing in other classes where you used `import android.app.Fragment`

**UPDATE:**
Remove `getApplicationContext()`

```
case 0:
            Intent firstpage= new Intent(MainActivity.this,DefaultTabs.class);
            startActivity(firstpage);
```

Comment: then i am get errors for case1,case2,case3 in displayView()

Comment: same thing you need to do in your HottestFragment(),RandomFragment(),and AllFragment();

Comment: changed in all fragments then also app crashing please check stacktrace